# Databound menu with icons

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a simple markup given below. DataContext is assigned at run-time.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="5" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="5" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="5" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="5" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Menu Name="GlobalMenu" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Text}" />
                <Setter Property="Icon">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}" />
            </Style>
        </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that menu item icons are drwn only for the first time. So menu items still exist, text is there, I'm able to change menu item text by changing bound DataContext object, so binding generally works, but icon is not drawn. Since icons are a little bigger, I notice that not only icon is not drawn, but menu item shrinks in size, like there is no icon at all.

Icon property on bound object looks like this

```
    public BitmapImage Image
    {
        get
        {
            byte[] image = _widget.CommandRelation.Command.Element.Image;

            if (image == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(image))
            {
                bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
                bitmapImage.EndInit();
            }

            return bitmapImage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A start is to try and debug the image binding. Place a debug value converter on the Image binding and see what DataContext is set.

Comment: because of the using the memory stream is disposed immediately, I am not sure if the way you set the StreamSource to the BitmapImage is correct meaning that bitmapImage would not need the stream anymore.

Comment: BitmapImage will not need stream, because I set bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create objects in a `Style` only one instance is created for all objects which use the style, this won't do as UI-elements can not be used in more than one place.

You can put the Image declaration in some (compiled) resource dictionary which is accessible from where the `Style` is used (`Style.Resources` are not compiled, so that will unfortunately not work) and set [`x:Shared`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx) on it to `false`, that way when you reference it in the `Setter.Value` via `StaticResource` a new instance is created every time and every `MenuItem` gets its own icon.

e.g. try this:

```
<Menu Name="GlobalMenu" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="Icon" x:Shared="False" Source="{Binding Image}" />
    </Menu.Resources>
    <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Text}" />
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource Icon}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}" />
        </Style>
    </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Actually, all images are dynamic (loaded from files) so I probably will have to fill this resource dictionary in code, which is a little complex for me, because I'm WPF newbie. May be you can point me to some article?

Comment: @adontz: It does not matter where the images come from the only problem is the Image-control, you need to have more than one.

Comment: I mean, I have no idea how to do what you said :-)

Comment: @adontz: Have a look at my example then.